# Create DSL connection on Xububtu 12.04

Tags: network-manager, dns, pppoe, dsl

How do create DSL connection on Xububtu 12.04?

I have been provided with a username, password and 2 DNS settings (prefeired and alternative).

On windows I could key in all info and connect within seconds.

In Xubuntu I use `sudo pppoeconf` to key in username and password. Then manually type 2 DNS nameserver in  with `sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf` and try to connect.

The connection was not established, please help if anybody can.

Comment: Hm. Just a thought: /etc/resolv.conf isn't really used anymore in Ubuntu. NetworkManger takes care of that. What I would recommend is finding your current connection (wireless, ethernet, etc.) in the Network Settings GUI and updating your DNS servers via that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu no longer utilizes the /etc/resolv.conf. Your guess is as good as mine as to why. So, to set up DNS correctly, try setting your DNS settings inside of the Network Manager GUI. You can get to this by clicking the networking icon in the upper right and going to Network Settings. From here, select your DSL connection (I'm assuming it's ethernet, but it could be WiFi) and then go to "Options..." and go to the IPv4 settings.

Just a side thought, I don't believe you should have to configure PPPoE client side. Shouldn't your modem take care of that for you? It's been a while since I dealt width direct-to-modem computers, so I could be wrong.